# JavaScript Error when using Flash Forms in ColdFusion 9

Tags: flash, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm having a problem with Flash Forms on ColdFusion 9 that worked perfectly under ColdFusion 8. When viewing the flash form in the browser, the form elements themselves display correctly, but the data for each field is not rendered in the input elements, and not present when submitting the form. When the page loads, I get an error:

```
964024021.mxml.cfswf:1 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: updateHiddenValue
```

The function `updateHiddenValue` is a function that's defined in `/CFIDE/scripts/cfform.js`, which is getting loaded into the page. If I use the Console and run the function directly, it runs without a problem:

[image]

To try and figure out why this might be happening, I fired up Charles and watched the requests to the server. As you can see in the screenshot below, the .js files receive 200 responses showing that they're good to go, but the `cfswf` requests are getting "connection closed" errors, and then 200 requests. The `cfswf` requests are obviously finishing correctly, or I wouldn't see the flash form at all.

[image]

So I need to figure out why I'm getting these `.js` errors so I can get this flash form workng. I can only assume that the error is originating from the flash side of things or via Flash Remoting (?), I just have no idea how to debug this issue and get things moving forward.

Comment: Looks like it is called once unsuccessfully then called successfully. .cfswf files would be the actual compiled Flash file right? Not a call to a CFC.  Where's the js file that includes the updateHiddenContent() function?

Comment: `cfform.js` is the one that contains that function, which is third in the list of requested files.

Comment: seems like a sync problem.  have you tried adjusting the cache for the cfswf files? Maybe they need to recompile each time. There's an attribute setting I think.

Comment: I've not seen a flip to switch for that one, but I'll do some digging. As it stands, I always get a 200 for the cfswf files, and not a 304. So it's doing a new request. I just need to verify that it's generating a new swf file I guess.

Comment: I'm trying to remember. We did a flash form app about 5 years ago (cf7 or 8) and we were not happy with the results so we have avoided using them.

Comment: Yeah, I may end up rewriting this with jQuery. This app was build more than 5 years ago, and has survived transitions from CFMX up to 8. It's gotten a little long in the tooth, and probably needs to be reworked anyway. Just trying not to rewrite any more than necessary. Was hoping I was missing something easy.

Comment: Dan are you getting this with ANY Flash Form, or just this specific one?  If it's "any form", can you post a self-contained repro case for us to look @ and dissect.

Comment: I'm not getting any flash forms from the server at all.

Comment: What version of Flash are you using? What browsers are you using on the working and non working versions?

Comment: Can you show the javascript where you call the function? It looks from the error like you are accessing it as a variable instead of a function.

Comment: That's just it. I'm not calling it. This is something built in to ColdFusion's flash forms, and it's failing on load. The function will execute in the console, but no via the default CF code execution.

Comment: I know this is completely non-constructive but please... for the love of Pete.  Please stop using flash forms people.  They cause more havoc then they solve.

Comment: @DaveFerguson I already did :). That's what I get for having 8 year old apps on my server :)

Answer (score 2):

I occurred with the same error while i was developing one application .
You might be declaring some other script before this which will bring conflict .
Comment all others and try again .
Mine was resolved by doing this hit an trial method . I commented all scripts run my application , it worked out .

Answer (score 0):

The script tag which references `cfform.js` is probably loading after the object tag that references the swf. Check the order by viewing source the browser to verify. Use `mm.cfg` with [Vizzy](http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/wiki/Troubleshooting) and a [debug player](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#main-pars_text_5) to see what events are happening on the Flash side. Here's some other resources which may help troubleshoot:

- [Using ActionScript in Flash forms](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec10372-7ff0.html)
- [cfajaxproxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-79f9.html)
- [cfajaxproxy and the head tag](http://www.thefaberfamily.org/search-smith/2012/03/coldfusion-cfajaxproxy-and-the-head-tag/)
- [Calling cfform validation from custom javascript functions](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Calling_cfform_validation_from_custom_javascript_f-16276.html)